# Android : How do I intercept Android system volume panel UI in my app?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on an app where I am looking to intercept the volume change key press and show my custom UI. Something like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=leedroiddevelopments.volumepanel

So requirement is whenever use tries to change volume in my app, instead of showing system UI for volume control panel, I want to show my own UI.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is foreground, you can handle the media keys like normal keys.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events

If the foreground app don't handle the media key, the system will handle it and show the volume ui.